# Как запустить игру Minecraft из своего лаунчера?

Tags: java, netbeans, launcher

Делаю свой лаунчер для проекта.
Сделал загрузку клиента, авторизацию, загрузку новостей из группы вк, всё отлично. Но столкнулся с основной проблемой: запуск игры.

Я декомпилировал другие лаунчеры, смотрел код там, но нужной инфы это мне не дало. Документация на эту тему отсутствует, инфа на форумах устарела. Может кто знает, как запустить игру внутри своего кода?

Древо папок:

---

/assets/

/(Папка конкретного клиента с игрой)/

/versions/

/versions/(version.jar)

/versions/natives/

/versions/libraries/

---

Я пробовал создавать ProcessBuilder с заданными параметрами, но это мне ничего не дало. Насколько я знаю, надо вызывать метод Launch в launchwrapper.jar. К слову, планируется запускать только Forge версии игры, от 1.2.5, до 1.13.

Буду рад за любую помощь :3

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, нужно перейти в папку natives, -Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%.minecraft\bin\natives" текущего клиента и выполнить команду -net.minecraft.client.Minecraft

В итоге команда будет выглядеть вот так. "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java" -Xms0000m -Xmx0000m -cp "%APPDATA%.minecraft\bin*" -Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%.minecraft\bin\natives" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft "nickname"

Comment: Объедините ответы и удалите меньший из них

Comment: Нет, это так не работает.
Для новых версий надо создавать фрейм и вставлять апплет, инициализирующий игру, а для старых - вызывать метод Main в джарнике версии. Но вот только какой код должен иметь апплет и фрейм - мне неизвестно.